# Is there a school of Hinduism that has similarities with the Sufi theological view?

Tags: brahman

In Sufi theology, the Godhood has three levels:

-الأحدية=الذات the ego.
-الأسماء الإلهية the Divine Names.
-الأعيان الثابتة the primordial architypes.

Humanity is reflection of the Divine Names.

Is there a school of Hinduism that has similarities with the Sufi theological view?

Comment: Read about Bhakti marg.

Comment: @Just_Do_It do you mean Bhakti marga?

Comment: yes i mean Bhakti marga

Comment: not sure what you mean by DIvine Names or Primordial Architypes...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Divine Names are the second level of Godhood. Primordial Architypes=Fixed Essences Are the third level of Godhood.